# join tables from a library

Tags: sas, sas-macro

hi am trying to append the data-sets from a library which contain a specific column variable in them.for example i want to append those data-sets which contain the name column in them from myfile library.

below is my sample code--->

```
libname myfile'\c:data';



 proc sql noprint ;
      select distinct catx(".",libname,memname) into :DataList separated by " "
        from dictionary.columns
        where libname = upcase(myfile) and upcase(name);
    quit;
```

Comment: 'Typo' (missing comparison) in your where clause, `and upcase(name);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the type of the variable is consistent across all datasets something as simple as SET will work:

```
Data want;
      Set &datalist;
Run;
```

Comment: Your original code needs to be modified. My answer is not related to that. There's a question on here recently regarding this question. Does it have to have all 3 variables? What if only 2 are present?

Comment: Name in ('age', 'sex', 'name') with appropriate mods for case sensitivity.

Comment: Your code in OP indicated macro variable name, I didn't choose it. Verify your code.

Comment: Actually scratch that, I've already indicated in another Q of yours why your original code is incorrect. Jumping between Qs confuses things. The other Q had a full solution.